# React-Navigation v5 - transparency between stack navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

Hey I have a problem with transparency when using more than one **Stack.Navigator**.

I create 2 **Stack.Navigators** -> one for **Screens**, and one for **Popups**. 
The issue is, that my **Popups** has transparent backgrounds, and in this case, i need to show **Screens** in the background. It was working in react.navigation v4, and now in v5 I can't find any solution how to solve this issue.

**SNACK** https://snack.expo.io/@m.jachym/react-navigation-stacks-transparency

[navigation structure img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEXjy.png)

*There is two **Stack.Navigator**s, because **Stack.Navigator** for Popups has different and much more complicated **screenOptions**. 
Also, in [Docs about nesting navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/nesting-navigators.html) there is an advice to put one **Stack.Navigator** inside another. In this case the issue is, that when you set parent **Stack.Navigator** headerMode="screen", and children **Stack.Navigator** headerMode="none", the childrens headerMode is inherited from parent. The same problem is with other properties - that's why the structure of my navigation is as it is.

Idk that i'm doing something wrong, or thats the issue of new version of react-navigation and I should write to react-navigation team?*

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that you want to have your `Screens` stack in the background when you show your screens in the `Modals` stack. You have set transparent background for screens in the modal stack but your screen containing the `Modals` stack itself doesn't have a transparent background.

You need to make the screen containing `Modals` stack transparent as well:

```js
<Stack.Screen
  name="Modals"
  component={Modals}
  options={{ cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "transparent" } }}
/>
```

> the childrens headerMode is inherited from parent. The same problem is with other properties - that's why the structure of my navigation is as it is.

Navigators don't inherit configuration of their parent navigators. In case of you are talking about navigator configuration (props) and screens, navigator's configuration is not for screens (e.g. screens don't have `headerMode`).

You don't need so many navigators. A single navigator like this is fine:

```js
const modalOptions = {
  headerShown: false,
  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "transparent" },
  cardOverlayEnabled: true,
  cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current: { progress } }) => ({
    cardStyle: {
      opacity: progress.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 0.5, 0.9, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7]
      })
    },
    overlayStyle: {
      opacity: progress.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 0.6],
        extrapolate: "clamp"
      })
    }
  })
};

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="NewPopup"
        component={NewPopup}
        options={modalOptions}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Popup" component={Popup} options={modalOptions} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Comment: Oh i get it now. Thank you for help, and for react-navigation 5.x aswell :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add props in stack screen tag as mention below

<Stack.Screen name="ScreenName" component={component} options={{ presentation: "transparentModal"}}></Stack.Screen>